# I'm using Async/Await but it still logs after another piece of code

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to use the Fetch API syncronously, so I wrap it in `async/await`, and for the testing I `console.log` some text after, and still this log comes before the log of the fetch call:

```
async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch(
        'fetch_url', {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    );
    return response.text();        
}

fetchData().then(response => console.log(response));

console.log("Second Log");
```

But the output is:

```
> Second Log
> Some Response From The Server
```

Comment: "*I want to use the Fetch API syncronously,*" you cannot

Comment: This is actually expected behavior. JavaScript is a single-threaded language and the code runs in order. The console.log("Second Log") statement is executed before the fetchData() promise is resolved, so it will always be logged first.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma "single-theaded language" is one of the biggest misconceptions perpetuated about JS. It isn't and it cannot be.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve similar behavior to jQuery AJAX ? Or if I choose to use the fetch API I should start getting used to the way fetch works asynchronously? I just thought that if I use async/await it would hold further code execution until promise is resolved but clearly that's not the case

Comment: @Stackerito there is no reason not to use it asynchronously. Or you can use further `await`s in the code by using more `async` functions which is essentially the same but looks different.

Comment: @VLAZ do you have good resource to read on good practices when using fetch API or asynchronous calls in general? I feel like if I start using fetch instead of jQuery AJAX I'm going to have to take care of many new things, it just feels different

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch Also, jQuery isn't at all different, `$.ajax()` is also async.

Comment: Ok good to know. I think the way it's used and the syntax of jQuery makes it then feel like it's sync. Will need to take a deeper look into that now

Answer (score 0):

Your second console.log must be wrapped in an async function to achieve the expected behavior. Try the following:

```js
async function fetchData() {
    const data = await fetch(
        'fetch_url', {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    ).then(response => response.text())
    
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Second log");
}
```